# semantic-ui - avatar images not included in build?

Tags: semantic-ui

I have just installed semantic-ui with nodejs. I have added the code for selectbox with avatar images from the semantic ui site. Now I come to know that semantic-ui doesn't provide any images with its package (the '/images/avatar/small/jenny.jpg' is just blank).

Is there any provision to download those images? Or do I need to download those images separately from some other site?

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: I think images are not incleded, but you can download them from semantic ui website.

Answer (score 2):

Indeed thos images aren't download with semantic. If you want to access them you can reach them with semantic url. By example : `https://semantic-ui.com/images/avatar/small/jenny.jpg`